# Conditional nav on ionic slider

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have configured my Ionic slider to have nav buttons as I am developing a PWA and want to include mouse interactions on desktops. I wanted to have some conditionals run to hide the PREV button when slider is at beginning and hide the NEXT button when on the last slide. I checked out solution at [Hide and show on click in the ionic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42392137/hide-and-show-on-click-in-the-ionic-2) and made some code work for this.

My issue is that the PREV button is not automatically hidden when Ionic slider is first presented. I cannot get this to work for me as I have initiated the check using the slideChanged() method and I don't know how to hide the PREV button on initiation (before interacting with slider).

Here is my code:

**TS File:**

```
slideChanged() {
    if (this.slides.isEnd()) {
        this.hideNext = !this.hideNext;
    }
    else if (this.slides.isBeginning()) {
        this.hidePrev = !this.hidePrev;
    }
    else {
        console.log("slide changed");
        this.hideNext = true;
        this.hidePrev = true;
    }
}
```

**HTML Template**

```
<ion-icon *ngIf="hidePrev" name="ios-arrow-back" float-left class="slideNav prevSlide" (click)="prevSlide()"></ion-icon>
<ion-icon *ngIf="hideNext" name="ios-arrow-forward" float-right class="slideNav nextSlide" (click)="nextSlide()"></ion-icon>
<ion-slides (ionSlideDidChange)="slideChanged()" pager #imageSlides>
    <ion-slide *ngIf="data.video">
        <video controls poster="../../assets/imgs/{{category | slug}}/{{data.video}}-poster.jpg">
            <source src="../../assets/imgs/{{category | slug}}/{{data.video}}.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let image of data.featured_image">
        <img src="../../assets/imgs/{{category | slug}}/{{image}}.jpg" class="featured-image"/>
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ionSlideReachEnd` and `ionSlideReachStart` events :

**TS File**

```
slideChanged() {
  if (this.slides.isEnd()) {
    this.hideNext = !this.hideNext;
  }
  else if (this.slides.isBeginning()) {
    this.hidePrev = !this.hidePrev;
  }
  else {
    console.log("slide changed");
    this.hideNext = true;
    this.hidePrev = true;
  }
}

reachedStart() {
    this.hidePrev = true;
}

reachedEnd() {
    this.hideNext = true;
}
```

**HTML Template**

```
<ion-icon *ngIf="hidePrev" name="ios-arrow-back" float-left class="slideNav prevSlide" (click)="prevSlide()"></ion-icon>
<ion-icon *ngIf="hideNext" name="ios-arrow-forward" float-right class="slideNav nextSlide" (click)="nextSlide()"></ion-icon>
<ion-slides (ionSlideDidChange)="slideChanged()" (ionSlideReachEnd)="reachedEnd()" (ionSlideReachStart)="reachedStart()" pager #imageSlides>
  <ion-slide *ngIf="data.video">
    <video controls poster="../../assets/imgs/{{category | slug}}/{{data.video}}-poster.jpg">
        <source src="../../assets/imgs/{{category | slug}}/{{data.video}}.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide *ngFor="let image of data.featured_image">
    <img src="../../assets/imgs/{{category | slug}}/{{image}}.jpg" class="featured-image"/>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion but edited it to hide the arrow on the reachedStart() function: this.hidePrev = !this.hidePrev;
It works initially - however, when navigating back to first slide - the back button then reappears. I think it is being called by the slideChanged function.

Comment: You can keep my functions and change your slideChanges function like this : if (this.slides.isEnd()) {
    this.hideNext = true;
  } else {
    this.hideNext = false;}
if (this.slides.isBeginning()) {
    this.hidePrev = true;
  } else {
    this.hidePrev = false;
  }

Comment: Ha ha yes, I already did something similar with the logic. I might have to write a bit more for sliders that only have 1-2 images in my app...

Comment: I had to reverse your boolean statements for your suggestion to work @Jerome. But it was in fact a cleaner solution than I had come up with.

Answer (score 0):

with Ionic 2, change slideChanged() like this

```js
slideChanged() {
  this.hideNext = !this.slides.isEnd();
  this.hidePrev = !this.slides.isBeginning();
}
```

with Ionic 3, 4 & 5 (with Promises),
change slideChanged() like this

```js
slideChanged() {
  this.slides.isEnd()
    .then(s => this.hideNext = !s }

  this.slides.isBeginning()
    .then(s => this.hidePrev = !s }
}
```